# "Scroll to top" in mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have developed a website in the following url.

http://appail.xyz/nhatcfinal/

It has "scroll to to" in desktop version, But not in mobile version.

How can customize to "Scroll to top" in mobile version?

I'm not perfect with javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$('.scrollUpButton').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Raguzzini, This is for "mobile scroll to top" ??

Answer (score 0):

Your Scroll to top is working fine, you just need to add media query for mobile device is,

```
 @media (max-width:767px) {
 #toTop{
 right: 30px;
 }}
```

For sticky header logo, add following CSS code using your jquery for the sticky header.

```
 .show-fixed-logo{
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  display: inline-block; 
  left: 0; 
  opacity: 1; 
  z-index: 1013; 
  width: 125px;}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: @Dora one more thing i'm struggling with javascript or JQuery,
The logo is not visible in sticky menu in desktop version.

Comment: .show-fixed-logo{position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1013;
    width: 125px;}

Comment: add this class when the header is sticky, hope this will helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161024/discussion-between-sunil-dora-and-kumar).

Comment: @Dora, I have disabled theme option sticky menu, and managed with CSS.
Thanks for the help.  :)